# Use both Primary key and secondary index in one query.(Spanner/MySQL/Postgres)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, google-cloud-spanner

What index will be used if I query on both the primary key and an indexed column.

Let's say PK of table(data) is (uid,id) and we have an index on a column (eid).

Schema:
[image]

SQL query:

```
Select * from data where uid=121 or eid = 'name'
```

I'm not sure if both the primary key index and secondary index will be used for it. It's an `or` query.

And is this behaviour consistent in postgresql, google cloud spanner and mysql?

Comment: Check your query plans. It depends on the data as well, something you didn't mention. PostgreSQL would most likely use both indexes, depending on the data in P2.

Comment: @FrankHeikens added the schema

Comment: As far as being consistency between databases, **never** depend on it regardless of the specific databases. Further, it is not guaranteed  to be consistent within the same query on the same database (physically the same one) at different times and different data conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The query planner define which index(es) is best to use.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-optimizer.html

It may change depending the where criteria.

Greetings, Alejandro